Pos_hint of label in FloatLayout (Kivy)
I want to put the self.menu_label1 starting after 2% of screen size using the python file... For this, I insert the label in this way:
self.menu_label1 = Label(text=f"01. Data Selection", color=(0,0,0,1), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'x':0.02,'center_y':0.85})
However, when the screen is maximized, the first letters of the label don't appear in the screen... When I insert this logic of pos_hint in kivy file, it works correctly, but in python file not... How to do that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
